# JS: Convert array of objects into objects by specific key

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
const arr = [ {"2021-08-26": { selected: true }}, {"2021-08-27": { selected: true }}, {"2021-08-28": { selected: true }} ];

// const expected = {
//   "2021-08-26": {
//     selected: true
//   },
//   "2021-08-27": {
//     selected: true
//   },
//   "2021-08-28": {
//     selected: true
//   }
// }


console.log(Object.fromEntries(arr))
```

I have such an array. What's the best way to convert it into `expected` format? Date should be used as a key

Comment: You'll have to write code, which you do not appear to have even attempted to do.

Answer (score 3):

Uses one `Array.reduce` and (`Object.assign` or `...` **spread operator**) if don't consider how to process duplicate `date`.

```js
const arr = [ {"2021-08-26": { selected: true }}, {"2021-08-27": { selected: true }}, {"2021-08-28": { selected: true }} ];

function convert(items) {
  return items.reduce((pre, cur) => ({...pre, ...cur}), {})
  // return items.reduce((pre, cur) => Object.assign(pre, cur), {})
}
console.log(convert(arr))
```